# A safe wrapper around a custom pointer type?

Tags: pointers, rust

I'm trying to create a data structure that holds a reference to a parent and children, something like this :

```rust
pub struct TreeBox<T> {
    value: T,
    parent: Option<*mut TreeBox<T>>,
    children: Vec<*mut TreeBox<T>>,
}
```

The idea is that this structure can have a parent and children, and when dropped it would warn both the parent and the children that it does not exist anymore:

```rust
impl<T> Drop for TreeBox<T> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        for child in self.children.iter() {
            unsafe {
                let child = &mut **child;
                child.parent = None;
            }
        }
        if let Some(parent) = self.parent {
            unsafe {
                let parent = &mut *parent;
                for (i, child) in parent.children.iter().enumerate() {
                    if *child == self {
                        parent.children.remove(i);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, nothing prevents me from doing this:

```rust
let mut tree_box: TreeBox<String> = String::from("Hello").into();
let child = tree_box.create_child(String::from("World"));

let child_ref = tree_box.children().next().unwrap();
drop(child);

println!("child_ref: {}", child_ref.value());
assert_eq!(child_ref.value(), &"World".to_string());
```

This example works when the functions are implemented like below, and I am getting the value of the children back even after dropping it. Now, I'm guessing this is unsafe and I am accessing dropped memory but since it have not been replaced it works fine.

I would like to create a safe wrapper around this struct, so what mechanisms could I implement to prevent such thing ?

```rust
impl<T> TreeBox<T> {
    pub fn create_child(&mut self, value: T) -> TreeBox<T> {
        let child = TreeBox{
            value,
            parent: Some(self),
            children: Vec::new(),
        };
        let child_ref = &child_ref as *const TreeBox<T> as *mut TreeBox<T>;
        self.children.push(child_ref);
        child
    }

    pub fn value(&self) -> &T {
        &self.value
    }

    pub fn children(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &TreeBox<T>> {
        self.children.iter().map(|child| {
            unsafe {
                &**child
            }
        })
    }
}

impl<T> From<T> for TreeBox<T> {
    fn from(value: T) -> Self {
        TreeBox{
            value,
            parent: None,
            children: Vec::new(),
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Gonna leave this here since it seems somewhat relevant as trees are just a generalization of lists: [Rust with too many linked lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/)

Comment: Well since your example code supposedly compiles your implementations of some of `create_child`,  `chlidren`, `value` are unsound or more likely UB, since you don't show their implementation, we can't tell you which or why. Or `drop(child)` only drops a reference and is thus a noop.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with all methods. From the code you gave I cannot judge if your code is sound or not.

Comment: Your `create_child` is doubly UB, for one you can't cast a immutable pointer to a mutable one when it comes from an immutable reference.
Second, your so created pointer becomes dangling at the end of `create_child` so you can't ever create a reference from that pointer. There is no good way to return an owned object from the function (bar using shared ownership, like `Rc` or `Arc` or similar).

Comment: You probably want `Option<NonNull<TreeBox<T>>>` instead of `Option<*mut TreeBox<T>>` to allow for nieche optimization to happen.

Answer (score 1):

You've made a decision: the owner of the nodes will be the calling code (the code that creates them). This decision is, to put it simply, wrong (or it is highly likely it is wrong).

Implementing a safe interface for such data structure is hard. *Really* hard. Forget it, even developing a correct *unsafe* implementation for such code is extremely hard (and you didn't do it, not correctly). You should not mess with it unless you *really* know what you're doing. And judging by the code you wrote, you probably don't.

If you want to take a look at how such data structure is implemented, look at the intrusive linked lists of `tokio`. They're simpler than trees, but they still require convoluted code, with undecided details of Rust and the hardest parts of it (pinning, for example).

But you probably don't *need* it to be this way: in a typical data structure in Rust, the owner of the nodes is *the data structure itself*. This is the case for `Vec`, for example, as well as for [`LinkedList`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.LinkedList.html).

`LinkedList` requires mutual pointers (next and previous), but as long as everything is internal, you can keep the encapsulation. Expose a safe interface to access the nodes, and manage everything internally. You can, for example, keep the same declaration of `TreeBox`, but instead of using pointers to *borrow* nodes, only the `parent` link will be borrowing, but the children links will be *owning* (conceptually; raw pointers by themselves don't indicate whether they're borrowing or owning). That means that you only expose references to them to the outside, but the tree allocates them and destroys them when needed.

Implementing such data structure is still hard; of course, the best is to avoid unsafe code at all (and either use `Rc<RefCell>` and `Weak<RefCell>`, or use indices or a library such as [`petgraph`](https://docs.rs/petgraph) that simplifies things). But this way, it is at least *feasible*.

Comment: Thanks !
to write most of this, I went back to C mode, were objects usually don't move around in memory and pointers stay valid. I might want to give a shot at a safe version first, with things like `Rc`.